Importing a Python dependency from a private repository causes docker buildx build on Kubernetes to fail
I have setup a Kubernetes pod to build Docker containers. The projects I'm building containers for have a Python dependency which is from a private repository. Here is the issue: if I run the docker buildx build ... command in my terminal, everything works.
If, however, I run the command through a Python scripts, it fails with
#1 ERROR: error for bootstrap "kube30": Unauthorized
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
ERROR: error for bootstrap "kube30": Unauthorized

Note that it only fails if I explicitly import the private dependency. If I remove the import, without changing anything else, the building process works. And again, only when going through a script: when using the command directly from cmdline, it works in either case.
What could be the problem?

It's difficult to help you out as you haven't provided any code.
Most likely an issue with the Python script not inserting all the environment variables needed to run the docker build process.
Since the issue is with a private repository, it's likely an issue with SSH.  Can you ensure the environment variables are available when running the build command:
env = os.environ.copy()
subprocess.run(
    ["docker", "buildx", "build", "--ssh", "default", "-t", "my-image", "."],
    env=env
)

